# how to figure out captive portal URL in java

Tags: java, android

I am trying to update an app that I wrote for Android that will automatically log a user into a captive portal at my university. The app worked fine last year with the portal URL hard coded in, however this year that won't work because they changed the server URL, I know what the URL is, so I simply changed it in my program ... which sort of works

There are two main problems, for me, with this approach.

1. hard coding is a pain in the ass to do every year, I also want to be able to make  it future proof, so that hard coding the URL won't be necessary

   for some unexplainable reason there are actually buildings on campus that will direct to the OLD authentication server, it truly boggles my mind why it would do that

I would like to be able to make an HTTP request and get the URL of the captive portal that is redirected to, how is that done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Captive portals generally will intercept users' HTTP requests and issue a "fake" redirect to the portal's authentication page. Or they can simply replace the actual response with the login page.

If yours is a redirect-to-login, then simply do something like trying to load `http://google.com`, which can reasonably be expected to be truly available for at least the next few years. If the response comes in as a redirect to some totally different site, the redirect url is highly likely to be the portal's login page.

If it's a replace-the-response-with-login, then you should try to contact a known page with some known content, and see what you get back. if the response you got doesn't match you should have gotten, then you've gotten the login page and can try tearing apart the response and finding the login form via DOM operations.

Comment: To add to this: rather than using http://google.com for the test, you can use the well-defined URLs like http://connectivitycheck.gstatic.com/generate_204 . Google uses this (and others) for captive portal detection. If you get a code 204, then you're online. If you don't, chances are you got redirected to the captive portal, as described above.

Answer (score 1):

Captivate portals uses 2 methods.

1. as described above. http redirect so the gateway takes you to another address.
2. ICMP - sending "better route" message

Still from my exprience on cases where non simple redirect happens the approach of expecting the redirect won't work.